# If I am on workspace 1, is there a way to hide the unity buttons from running programs on workspace 2 from showing up on workspace 1?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I'm making a keyboard shortcut to go from the porn-workspace I'm using back to Workspace 1 in a pinch, but it does me no good if unity toolbar is full of "Image Viewer" and porn sites or movie player.

Comment: Ah, the first honest person on this forum!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply hide Unity side bar when not in use and then switch with keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible in unity to show windows only from current workspace. However, there are bug reports about this issue and you are not the only one annoyed I can say. You can follow the situation on those:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/683170

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1027949